# How to replace GET param into friendly url?

Tags: node.js, express

I have a question about ExpressJS routing.

I am using this plugin for localization [i18n-express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/i18n-express)

Everyting works fine, but how i can change this

***site.com/?clang=es*** to ***site.com/es***  ?

Maybe i need use **.htaccess** with some config or? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The module itself unfortunately doesn’t support what you’re looking for, though I see you put in an issue about it.

Until they fix it, one workaround for you would be to add a middleware that takes that parameter and moves it to an expected location.  Register this middleware before the i18n middleware and it should work:

```
      app.param(“lang”, (req, res, next, id) => {
               req.query.clang = id; // or put it in the header
               next();
      });
```

You then need to mount all your routes as /:lang/whatever

Comment: added and then added the app.use('/:lang', index);
But translations doesnt work...
and i think app.param not executed...

Comment: app.param('lang', (req, res, next) => {
    req.query.clang = req.params.lang;
    next();
});

this way i see console.log in this function, but translations not works :(

Comment: Ok, I had my app.param call wrong, sorry I fixed that.  That said, i'm seeing the same problem as you now, and I think it has to do with how the module is using the values under the hood. The code they wrote is not pretty... I'm going to suggest you find a different library perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

Redirect should do the job here. You can try smth. similar if it suits your need.

```js
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  let clang = req.query('clang');
  if (!!clang) {
    res.redirect('https://your.site/' + clang);
  }
});
```

And to capture the route you want use the following code.

```js
app.get('/:language', function(req, res) {
  let lang = req.param('language');
});
```

Comment: What he's doing is changing his query param to route param, with your code is only catching the base request.

Answer (score -1):

If much simpler than manipulate the `.htaccess`. What you need to do is this:

```
app.get('/:lang', function (req, res) {
  console.log("choice lang is " +req.params.lang); // Should receive what you send as route param
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This isn’t at all correct, the i18n module the OP is using only supports cookies, querystring, and http headers.